# Pythonでcsvファイルから特定の情報を抽出したい

Tags: python, 正規表現

この質問は、コードをかなり書き換えてしまったので、もう大丈夫です。
次の質問⇓
[csvファイルから都道府県ごとに市の数をカウントしたい](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/93078/csv%e3%83%95%e3%82%a1%e3%82%a4%e3%83%ab%e3%81%8b%e3%82%89%e9%83%bd%e9%81%93%e5%ba%9c%e7%9c%8c%e3%81%94%e3%81%a8%e3%81%ab%e5%b8%82%e3%81%ae%e6%95%b0%e3%82%92%e3%82%ab%e3%82%a6%e3%83%b3%e3%83%88%e3%81%97%e3%81%9f%e3%81%84)

Pythonを用いて、都道府県地区町村のデータから、都道府県と市区町村を抽出したいと考えています（１の画像参照）。

ただPythonで画像２のエラーがでてしまったのですが、どのように解決すればいいのか分かりません。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: 「ただpythonで画像２のエラーがでてしまったのですが」とありますが、”画像２のエラー”とは何のエラーでしょうか？エラーであればエラーメッセージが表示されるはずなので、それをコピーして質問に追記してください。

Comment: すいません。失念していました。　　　　　　　TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-13-238a4b9d054a> in <module>
      4 with open(filename, encoding='Shift JIS', newline='') as f:
      5     csvreader = csv.DictReader(f)
----> 6     print(re.findall("都"|"道"|"県"|"府",csvreader))

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for |: 'str' and 'str'

Comment: csvファイルの内容を画像ではなくテキストで先頭5行程度貼っていただくと回答しやすくなるかと思います。コードも画像ではなくマークダウンで記述いただくと読みやすくなります。

Comment: merinoさん。丁寧にありがとうございます。次回からそのようにします。

Comment: 質問はいつでも編集できるので、次回からではなく「この質問」を修正してください。

Answer (score 1):

> 都道府県地区町村のデータから、都道府県と市区町村を抽出したい

`KEN_ALL.CSV` は [日本郵便 郵便番号データダウンロード 読み仮名データの促音・拗音を小書きで表記するもの](https://www.post.japanpost.jp/zipcode/dl/kogaki-zip.html) からダウンロードしたものかと思います。都道府県と市区町村の名前は、それぞれ 7 列目と 8 列目に記載されているので、それらを抽出することになります。

```py
import csv

filename = 'KEN_ALL.CSV'
prefs, cities = [], []
with open(filename, encoding='Shift JIS', newline='') as f:
    csvreader = csv.reader(f)
    for row in csvreader:
        prefs.append(row[6])  # 7列目: 都道府県名
        cities.append(row[7]) # 8列目: 市区町村名

# 重複を削除
prefs = [*{*prefs}]
cities = [*{*cities}]

print(prefs)    # 47件
# print(cities) # 1894件
```

Comment: ありがとうございます！！　追加で質問なのですが、最終的には、都道府県ごとに市の数を数えたいと考えています。市区町村に関して、市だけを抽出して（重複なく）、その数をカウントするにはどのようにすればよいのでしょうか。

Comment: 「余市郡仁木町」「芳賀郡市貝町」「西八代郡市川三郷町」などなど、郡名や町名に「市」が入っているものがあるので、単純に「〜市」という部分文字列を取り出すだけでは不十分です。「都道府県ごとに市の数を数えたい」とのことなので、KEN_ALL.csv ではなく、別のオープンデータを使う方が的確な結果を得られるかと思います。

Answer (score 0):

`re.search`について簡単な例を示します。

```
import re

s = ["東京都", "北海道", "長崎県", "京都府", "名古屋市"]
for i in s:
    print(re.search("都|道|県|府", i))
# <re.Match object; span=(2, 3), match='都'>
# <re.Match object; span=(2, 3), match='道'>
# <re.Match object; span=(2, 3), match='県'>
# <re.Match object; span=(1, 2), match='都'>
# None
```

正規表現は""で囲ってください。

Comment: 質問のコード（画像）が変わってしまったため、質問と回答が少々合わなくなってしまいました。